# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $W_1,W_2$ be two subsapces then $(W_1+W_2)^0=W_1^0\cap W_2^0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $W_1,W_2$ be two subsapces then

> $(W_1+W_2)^0=W_1^0\cap W_2^0.$

Comment: What's $\,^0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$f\in(W_1+W_2)^0\implies f(x)=0\;\;\forall\,x\in W_1+W_2\;,\;\;\text{and since}\;\;W_1\,,\,W_2\subseteq W_1+W_2\;\ldots$$

On the other hand

$$f\in W_1^0\cap W_2^0\implies f(x)=0\;\forall\,x\in W_1\;\text{and also}\;f(y)=0\;\forall\,y\in W_2,\; \text{and since}$$

$$\forall\,v\in W_1+W_2\;\;\exists \,x\in W_1\,,\,y\in W_2\;\;s.t.\;\;v=x+y\;\ldots$$

BTW, no finite dimension assumption needed here. It is needed in *other* inclusion, though...